# zombie.js xhr json always fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, zombie.js

I want to use zombie js to test my little node app.
I'm using the mock ressoures with zombie but when i write

body: object

in mock.the xhr always fail because of

```
Request Failed: parsererror, SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

when i write

body: 'json content'

xhr work well

To test this client js

```js
var xhrGetRiver = $.getJSON("api/1/settings/rivers/fs/")
xhrGetRiver.done(function(json) {
    console.log(json);
    $.each(json, function(index, fsriver) {
        insertFSRiver(fsriver);
    });
});
xhrGetRiver.fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
    var err = textStatus + ', ' + error;
    console.log("Request Failed: " + err);
});
```

I have write this test

```js
var data = [];
var json = {
  "id": "test",
  "properties": {
    "url": "/tmp",
    "server": "192.168.9.2",
    "port": 22,
    "username": "testUser",
    "password": "test",
    "protocol": "ssh",
    "update_rate": "15m",
    "includes": "*.docx"
  }
};
data.push(json);
this.browser.resources.mock('/api/1/settings/rivers/fs/', {
                statusCode: 200,
                headers:    { 'ContentType': 'application/json' },
                body: data  // xhr fail
                //body: '[ { "id":... ... } ]' // Work well
```

Answer (score 0):

in app i'am using Express framework and i use res.json the array from library.

res.json seem to stringify my array